# PHP file upload in mac with xampp

Tags: macos, xampp

I have been trying to figure out this issue(File upload) I am using xampp 8.0.7-0 with Big Sur in macbook, I have looked a lot of example from youtube and google there is ain't no single example with my version of the xampp, I guess the issue is directory adress because in other examples they have their xampp files in application folder but in my version it creates new server, also gives error 0 when I try to upload some images, so as far as I know there is no error also I already gave permissions and increased max file size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just moved all files and database to MAMP, same code worked, so don't use XAMPP to avoid this.